# Combine PHP exec, form and linux

Tags: php, linux

My brain has stopped working and I really want to combine this together:

I want to take input on the website, save it in a variable, and call it down to the Linux shell to make a command.

Here is what I have:

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
 <p>Kommando: <input type="text" name="cmd" /></p>
 <p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>



<?php
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: You need to use `$_POST['cmd']`, not `$command`, which is undefined. ***PLEASE NOTE:*** This is ***horrifically*** insecure. You need to do a lot of validation on the command before passing it to the shell, or you risk all kinds of terrifyingly bad hacks.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `$_POST['cmd']`, not `$command`. There is no variable named `$command` in your script.

***PLEASE NOTE:*** This is ***horrifically*** insecure. You need to do a lot of validation on the command before passing it to the shell, or you risk all kinds of terrifyingly bad hacks.

Please read about [command injection attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Command_Injection) and *never* pass anything you are not 100.000% sure is safe to the shell. That means you need to do both whitelisting and blacklisting, and you probably want a good WAF (web application firewall) backing you up. Ideally, you wouldn't use the user's input *at all*, except to pick one of several predefined commands.